# How add Cookies to http request header in ASP .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to get token array from https://token.learn.microsoft.com/accesstokens. This can be done by include cookies to the http request header. I already tested with postman. It works.

I have web application with ASP .Net core Mvc. It will authenticate with Azure AD. After user log in i need to send a API request include with 'Cookie' request header.

```
static async Task<string> SendURI(Uri u, HttpContent c, string token)
        {
            var response = string.Empty;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    RequestUri = u,
                    Content = c
                };

                HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(request);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    response = result.StatusCode.ToString();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
```

This is how I send the request. Its working fine for other request without cookie request header. But I need to know how to add cookies to this http request from my app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list#code-try-0 in this doc they using this method. I need the same effort with my app.  They send post request to https://token.learn.microsoft.com/accesstokens this with cookie header.

[screenshot of sample request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVIfy.jpg)

**UPDATE:**
adding header cookie to http request is can be done by help of post man code.

Now I face a challenge with creating custom cookie like ms doc using.

[cookie sample ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2G67.png)

How can I create customer cookie inside startup.cs file? for the content value what should to be included?

```
services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
                options.Cookie.Name = ".TokenAuthCookies";
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                options.Cookie.Domain = ".learn.microsoft.com";
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            });
```

How I change my above code accordingly to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fun life hack when using Postman:

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

I'm not sure if I understand the question.

If you have the value, just put it in the header

```
request.AddHeader("Cookie",value)
```

If you want to define your .net Core app to allow the use of Session Cookies you can try going to Startup.cs and in the ConfigureServices method add:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(_configuration["Cookies:ExpiresInSecond"]));
                options.Cookie.Name = _configuration["Cookies:CookiesName"];
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            });
```

the _configuration is taken from the appSettings.json file in your .NET Core project.

EDIT 2:

If you wish to set a value to your session Cookie, use:

```
_httpContext.HttpContext.Session.Set(KEY, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VALUE));
```

If you wish to get a value from your session Cookie:

```
_httpContext.HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue(KEY, out byte[] VALUE_BYTES);
var value = VALUE_BYTES == null ? "" : Encoding.ASCII.GetString(VALUE_BYTES);
```

If you wish to add the value you just pulled from Session Cookie to your request header use:

```
request.AddHeader("Cookie",value)
```

Hope that covers everything :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is cool. I didn't aware about that. Can I know how to put session cookie value inside request.AddHeader("Cookie","???")

Comment: This is my first time using api request with cookie header. I added the that cookie configuration to my startup class. One last question how do I pass the cookie value after that to request.AddHeader("Cookie",???).

Comment: Try running it with the configuration first. I think it should be enough
If you wish to add a specific Coockie to your header, well it's just as you wrote:
request.AddHeader("Coockie",[your value])

Comment: Thank you Yoni Ziv. I will try this out

Comment: Any idea how to get token auth cookies from startup.cs? Do i need to do extra steps other than above startup.cs file code? I updated the question.

Comment: Edited answer. Hope this answers the question

Comment: Its covers everything. Thanks again Yoni :)

Comment: if you can please help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575769/how-to-get-tokenauthcookies-cookie-from-docs-microsoft-com-in-asp-net-core-m Much appreciate :)