# How to get '.TokenAuthCookies' cookie from .docs.microsoft.com in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

Currently I am facing an issue with finding way to get cookie from '.learn.microsoft.com'. Please refer to the cookie details shown below.

```
Name: .TokenAuthCookies,
Domain: .doc.microsoft.com,
Path: /
```

[.TokenAuthCookies details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBHN9.png)

**Optional details**

My effort is to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list#code-try-0 do the same as the this API doc do. To authenticate this API request first they get tenant array from https://token.learn.microsoft.com/accesstokens this URL. To authenticate that They are using cookie by the name of `.TokenAuthCookies` from the API request (https://token.learn.microsoft.com/accesstokens) cookie header.

**Developed so far**

I enabled the session inside the startup class' `Configure` method:

```
app.UseSession();
```

I tried to create customer cookie; I don't have experience on this before. Inside startup class' `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40);
                options.Cookie.Name = ".TokenAuthCookies";
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                options.Cookie.Domain = ".learn.microsoft.com";
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            });
```

Inside controller, I need to put cookie value to here.

```
HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue(".TokenAuthCookies", out byte[] VALUE_BYTES);
           var value = VALUE_BYTES == null ? "" : Encoding.ASCII.GetString(VALUE_BYTES);

var client = new RestClient("https://token.learn.microsoft.com/accesstokens");
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                
                request.AddHeader("Cookie", value???);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Please refer to this screenshot of my MS Docs api request overview:

[Token API request overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi3AJ.jpg)

I just need to know how to get `.TokenAuthCookies` cookie to my app and put it my controller API request 'cookie' header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dglumesh :
Please look at:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/b355c94177caa58d4e8c59a07a13429dc3788395/3-WebApp-multi-APIs/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L55-L70,

It does what you want (without having to use a token auth cookies which is proprietary to docs.microsoft.doc, and which you should probably not use.

Comment: Thanks for your information regarding this. I was checking searching everywhere how should I get that cookie from my app. Ask bunch of senior devs.  In that case small limitation we have to face. That is log in person must need default tenant active subscription to run that tenant list api request. Otherwise it won't work. Thanks again :)