# Tenant not found error while getting token from microsoftonline url

Tags: c#, postman, httpclient, powerbi-rest-api

[image] [[image: postman request body]][image] I am trying to get token through https://login.microsoftonline.com by passing clientid and client secret, the same request generate token through Postman successfully, but from C# HttpClient, It is giving 'Tenent not Found' error.

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Uri baseUri = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com");
client.BaseAddress = baseUri;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");

HttpRequestMessage requestMessage;
var authenticationString = $"{DefaultConfig.ClientId}:{DefaultConfig.ClientSecret}";
var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = 
Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString));

requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx- 
xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token");
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", 
base64EncodedAuthenticationString);
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", 
"https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"));
requestMessage.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you add the Postman request to the description too please? So that we can confirm that it's the same

Comment: added the snapshots!

Comment: Your postman headers have 12 entries but in your request you are adding just the default request and authentication headers. Can you check if they are the same with Postman?

Comment: those are by default headers, I added the snapshot!

Comment: Try to attach the exact same headers to your requestMessage that you see in PostMan. I doubt you can do much for the `Postman-Token` and the content headers but as for the cookie header, here is a good link that can help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557796/17985195)

Comment: It's telling you it doesn't like the tenant ID, so console log what is actually being sent.  Does the baseURI and the tenant Id combined look correct.  If you've got a working request in Postman, you should be able to select the code snippet feature which should reply a working httpclient request.